# Why was the main character in Quantum Leap named "Sam Beckett"?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, quantum-leap

It seems very strange to me that the main character in Quantum Leap is named Sam Beckett, given that there was already a [very famous playwright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Beckett) with that name. They even acknowledge it in one episode ([Honeymoon Express](http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/Honeymoon_Express_%28episode%29)) when he reveals that he's a time traveler named Samuel Beckett and the woman he's talking to says, "Like the playwright?"

Is there some story behind why they chose this name rather than a name like Sam Beckworth or Sam Becker or something less confusing? I find it hard to believe that no one on that show realized the conflict before the start of the show.

**Update** Oddly enough, I stumbled across the 1988 show [China Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Beach), which has a main character named Private Samuel Beckett. Given that both shows were created at nearly the exact same time, I wonder if there was some common reason why two shows would both name a character the exact same name as a famous playwright.

Beckett died in 1989, which makes it unlikely either was a posthumous tribute to him, but China Beach is a show about Vietnam, and [Bellisario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_P._Bellisario) is known for his shows with military themes, so maybe there's some Samuel Beckett in the military space that they were both named after? I'm not turning anything up at the moment.

Comment: Unless Donald P. Bellisario happens to read this, how can anyone answer?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Presumably the same way they answer other behind the scenes questions - reference to some interview or book or something. Maybe the answer isn't out there, but that's a risk in all questions.

Comment: “something less confusing” — was anyone confused? Did they tune into Quantum Leap expecting a biography of the playwright?

Comment: Would you prefer he was named Billie Whitelaw?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Maybe confusing is the wrong word, but it's a bit weird. Like I wouldn't be *confused* if he was named Albert Einstein, but it'd certainly be weird, just ask [Albert Brooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Brooks).

Comment: @Paul Granted I was only 8 when Quantum Leap first aired, I hadn't known about the playwright Sam Beckett until I just read your question.

Comment: They should reboot Quantum Leap but have the main character be called Bertie Brecht or something.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR: Given the similarities in theme, the name is probably a reference to the playwright.**

---

In-universe, [**Dr. Sam Beckett**](http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/Samuel_Beckett) is named after his father, dairy farmer [John Samuel Beckett](http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/John_Samuel_Beckett). Out-of-universe, however, it's most likely that the name is a nod to playwright [Samuel Beckett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Beckett) and his work. There are simply too many coincidences to believe that the name is incidental.

Much of Samuel Beckett's work is concerned with the theme of time and how it affects our perception of the world (and ourselves). For instance:

- In his play "[Krapp's Last Tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krapp%27s_Last_Tape)", Beckett portrays a man listening to recordings from earlier in his life. As he re-visits these previous times in his life, his perception of both time and his own life is altered.
- Another example is the work titled "[Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_(play))", which details a single event from three different timeframes & viewpoints.
- Beckett's most famous work, "[Waiting for Godot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiting_for_Godot)", is about two men waiting for an event that never happens, but they keep waiting anyway

Now, compare these three themes with what we see in Quantum Leap:

- A time-traveller leaping through the years of his own lifetime, although generally unable to make any changes to his OWN past.
- A time-traveller who - more than once - experiences the same event through different eyes.
- A time-traveller who desperately wants to get back home, a goal which seems increasingly impossible as the show goes on.

**Simply put, the odds of this being a coincidence... are NOT in your favor.**

Comment: This is a pretty solid answer. Didn't know that about the themes in Beckett's work. I'm going to leave it open 1 more day if you don't mind in case someone comes up with any non-conjectural evidence.

Comment: Nicely done, sir!

Comment: New appreciation for an already wonderful show.